# Common way to add buildscipt dependencies to multiple gradle files

Tags: gradle

I created a custom plugin, which will be used in many other gradle files. Now to be able to apply the custom plugin, I need to add buildscript{} block in each of my gradle files (users of plugin).

I tried moving the buildscript{} block to another file (buildscript-deps.gradle) and use 'apply from: buildscript-deps.gradle' , but that does not help.

Is there a way to apply buildscript{} in common way?

Comment: can you show your gradle code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, see [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/inherit_inject_buildscript_dependencies_into_custom_script_within_subproject). What may help is installing the plugin in custom repository and then applying it to other scripts, not as a plain file (apply from: 'some.gradle') but as a repo dependency.